# How to get correct frame duration using ffmpeg?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, timestamp, duration

In my file "Video.avi", all **pkt_duration** attributes in video AVFrame are equal to 1.
But the **best_effort_timestamp** attributes in AVFrame for the first video frames are : 0, then 3, then 4, then 5, then 7 .. etc, which means for example that the duration of the first frame is 3 and not 1. (the time_base is 1/30)
Is there a better way to know the correct duration of a frame than reading the next frame and getting its **best_effort_timestamp** and computing the difference between the two **best_effort_timestamp**?
If not, is there a way to read only the header of the next packet just to get its **best_effort_timestamp** and not wasting time to decompress anything ?
Thank you for your help.